# Accessing child variables through higher level structures

Tags: c++, c

If I have these structures:

```
typedef struct { int x; } foo;
typedef struct { foo f; } bar;
```

Normally you would access `x` through `b.f.x`, but is there a way to set this up so that you can access element `x` without referring to `f`?

```
bar b;
b.x = ...
```

My first intuition is that you can't since there would be a possibility for name conflicts if two sub structures both had a member x and I can't figure out what the compile error would be.  However, I recall working in some frameworks where this was possible.

In C++ I worked in a framework once where `bar` existed, and you could access its members as member variables `this->x` from a different class.  I'm trying to figure out how that could be done.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can with C11:

**§ 6.7.2.1 -- 11**

> An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier with no tag is called an
>   anonymous structure; an unnamed member whose type specifier is a union specifier with
>   no tag is called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or union
>   are considered to be members of the containing structure or union. This applies
>   recursively if the containing structure or union is also anonymous.

So this code *might* work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x; } foo;
typedef struct { foo; } bar;

int main(void)
{
    bar b;
    b.x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", b.x);
}
```

The problem here is that different compilers disagree in my tests on whether a *typedef* is acceptable as a *struct specifier with no tag* The standard specifies:

**§ 6.7.8 -- 3**

> In a declaration whose storage-class specifier is `typedef`, each declarator defines an
>   identifier to be a typedef name that denotes the type specified for the identifier in the way
>   described in 6.7.6. *[...]* A `typedef` declaration does not introduce a new type, only **a
>   synonym for the type so specified.**

(emphasis mine) -- But does *synonym* also mean a *typdef-name* specifier is exchangeable for a *struct specifier*? `gcc` accepts this, `clang` doesn't.

Of course, there's no way to express *the whole member of type `foo`* with these declarations, you sacrifice your named member `f`.

Concerning your doubt about name collisions, this is what `gcc` has to say when you put another `int x` inside `bar`:

```
structinherit.c:4:27: error: duplicate member 'x'
 typedef struct { foo; int x; } bar;
                           ^
```

To avoid ambiguity, you can just *repeat the struct*, possibly `#define`d as a macro, but of course, this looks a bit ugly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x; } foo;
typedef struct { struct { int x; }; } bar;

int main(void)
{
    bar b;
    b.x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", b.x);
}
```

But **any conforming compiler should accept this code**, so stick to this version.

<opinion>This is a pity, I like the syntax accepted by `gcc` much better, but as the wording of the standard doesn't make it *explicit* to allow this, the only *safe bet* is to assume it's forbidden, so `clang` is not to blame here...</opinion>

If you want to refer to `x` by *either* `b.x` *or* `b.f.x`, you can use an additional anonymous union like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x; } foo;
typedef struct {
    union { struct { int x; }; foo f; };
} bar;

int main(void)
{
    bar b;
    b.f.x = 2;
    b.x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", b.f.x); // <-- guaranteed to print 1
}
```

This will *not* cause aliasing issues because of

**§ 6.5.2.3 -- 6**

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members

Comment: Fantastic response.  This does indeed answer the question.  Anonymous structures is what I was looking for, and it is very possible that I was looking into C++11 specific code.

Comment: @Stewart note my whole response talks about C11, **not** C++11. I don't know whether this is applicable to C++11 as well.

Answer (score 7):

**C**: Highly unrecommended, but doable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAR_STRUCT struct { int x; }

typedef BAR_STRUCT bar;

typedef struct {
    union {
        bar b;
        BAR_STRUCT;
    };
} foo;

int main() {
  foo f;
  f.x = 989898;
  printf("%d %d", f.b.x, f.x);

  return 0;
}
```

Anonymous structs are a widly-spread extension in standards before C11.

**C++**:
The same as in C, you can do here but anonymous structs are not part of any C++ standard, but an extension.
Better use inheritance, or do not use this shortcut at all.

Of course, do not use something like `#define x b.x`)).

Comment: I think this must be what I've seen in the past.  I remember lots of issues regarding structure alignment.  Of course the `#define` is right out.

Comment: If you have exactly the same `struct` definition in the union there wont be any alignment issues.

Comment: @Yuki and therefore, the `#define` to do something like this is in fact a *good idea*.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please, how is that a good idea? Because I see a problem: you cannot type `x` anywhere where you macros is defined.

Answer (score 5):

In C you can't access members of members like this.

You can however access members of an anonymous inner struct:

```
struct bar {
    struct {
        int x;
    }
};

...
struct bar b;
b.x = 1;
```

In C++ you use inheritance:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
};

struct bar: public foo {
};

...
struct bar b;
b.x = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C (99 and onward) you can access the common initial sub-sequence of union members, even if they weren't the last member written to<sup>1</sup>.

In C11, you can have anonymous union members. So:

```
typedef struct { int x; } foo;
typedef struct {
  union {
    foo f;
    int x;
  };
} bar;
```

---

1. Yes, that applies to structures. But according to the standard:

   - A structure pointer, suitably converted, points to the first member.
   - A union pointer, suitably converted, points to any union member.
   - So their location in memory is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in C. In C++ however you can use inheritance which is probably what you were thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you can use inheritance and member name conflicts are sort of resolvable with `::` and treating the base classes as members.

```
struct foo { int x; };
struct bar : foo { };

struct foo1 { int x; };
struct bar1 : foo1 { char const* x; };

bar b;
bar1 b1;
int main()
{
    return b.x + b1.foo1::x;
}
```

In standard C, it's impossible, however several compilers (gcc, clang, tinycc) support a similar thing as an extension (usually accessible with `-fms-extensions` (on gcc also with `-fplan9-extensions` which is a superset of `-fms-extensions`)), which allows you to do:

```
struct foo { int x; };
struct bar { struct foo; };
struct bar b = { 42 }; 
int main()
{
   return b.x;
}
```

However, there's no resolution for conflicting member names with it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, it is possible in two ways.  The first is to use inheritence.  The second is for `bar` to contain a reference member named `x` (`int &x`), and  constructors that initialise `x` to refer to `f.x`.

In C, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the C standard guarantees that there isn't padding before the first member of a struct, there isn't padding before the `foo` in `bar`, and there isn't padding before the `x` in `foo`.  So, a raw memory access to the start of `bar` will access `bar::foo::x`.

You could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _foo
{
    int x;
} foo;

typedef struct _bar
{
    foo f;
} bar;

int main()
{
    bar b;
    int val = 10;

    // Setting the value:
    memcpy(&b, &val, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", b.f.x);

    b.f.x = 100;


    // Reading the value:
    memcpy(&val, &b, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

As others have noted, C++ offers a more elegant way of doing this through inheritance.