# C11 struct inheritance with anonymous struct

Tags: c, inheritance, gcc, struct, c11

I saw [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14523823/108802) to implement some kind of `struct` inheritance with anonymous `struct` in C11, and wanted to try it out. Here is what I have:

```
struct struct_a {
    int aa;
};

struct struct_b {
    struct struct_a;
    int bb;
};

int main(void)
{
    volatile struct struct_b my_b;
    my_b.aa = 5; /* not a member of my_b */
    my_b.bb = 6;

}
```

Result from gcc:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 struct_extend.c 
struct_extend.c:11:20: warning: declaration does not declare anything
     struct struct_a;
                    ^
struct_extend.c: In function ‘main’:
struct_extend.c:18:9: error: ‘volatile struct struct_b’ has no member named ‘aa’
     my_b.aa = 5; /* not a member of my_b */
```

Relevant:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516
```

Is this not implemented in my compiler, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are anonymous structs and unions useful for in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11)

Comment: You need something after `struct struct_a;` in `struct struct_b` declaration.

Comment: [also related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524573/2371524) .. bottom line: to be sure your code is conforming without doubt, you have to use a quite verbose form, unfortunately.

Comment: If you use `gcc -std=c++11` it supports real inheritance...

Answer (score 6):

According to [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields) reference : use `-fms-extensions` flag, Which will enable the this feature.

> - Unless `-fms-extensions` is used, the unnamed field must be a structure or union definition without a tag (for example, ‘struct {
>     int a; };’). If `-fms-extensions` is used, the field may also be a
>     definition with a tag such as `‘struct foo { int a; };’`, a reference
>     to a previously defined structure or union such as ‘struct foo;’, or a
>     reference to a typedef name for a previously defined structure or
>     union type.
> - The option `-fplan9-extensions` enables `-fms-extensions` as well as two other extensions. First, a pointer to a structure is
>     automatically converted to a pointer to an anonymous field for
>     assignments and function calls.

I have used following command on GCC, it's working fine.

```
gcc -std=c11 -O2 -Wall -fms-extensions -pedantic -pthread ls.c
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard only allows structure and unions without a tag as unnamed members:

[6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers - Paragraph 13](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p13)

> **An unnamed member** whose type specifier is a **structure specifier with
>   no tag** is called an anonymous structure; an unnamed member whose type
>   specifier is a union specifier with no tag is called an anonymous
>   union. The members of an anonymous structure or union are considered
>   to be members of the containing structure or union. This applies
>   recursively if the containing structure or union is also anonymous.

Yours clearly has a tag, so it's not valid C. What the answer you linked to did is not any better either. The way to do it in a standard compliant way, is sadly quite verbose:

```
struct struct_b {
    union {
        struct struct_a _aa;
        struct { int aa; };
    };
    int bb;
};
```

Which really isn't anything to be impressed by. One can perhaps use a macro to avoid repeating the member declarations, but it's a code smell by now.

Comment: That version of the code will fail under "modern" interpretations of the aliasing rules if anything tries to take the address of `_aa` and access the structure using the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are attempting to make an anonymous unnamed struct containing `int aa` in `struct_b`, similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct struct_b {
    struct {
        int aa;
    };
    int bb;
};

int main(void)
{
    volatile struct struct_b my_b;
    my_b.aa = 5; /* now a member of my_b */
    my_b.bb = 6;

    printf ("my_b.aa: %d\nmy_b.bb: %d\n", my_b.aa, my_b.bb);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strc2
my_b.aa: 5
my_b.bb: 6
```

This follows directly from the standard section cited by StoryTeller.

Comment: I see. What would be the point of grouping the members of the inside struct, if it needs to be explicitly defined there anyway?

Comment: That's the $100 question. I've toyed with it a bit, adding multiple levels and multiple types, and I don't see any benefit to embedding an unnamed anonymous struct within a struct. Seems to me just declaring the variables within the original struct itself makes much more sense. I'd have to see the standards committee minutes where this was argued over, but I suspect that this was intended to provided the anonymous unnamed `struct` within a `union` for `bitfield` purposes and the fact you can do it with a struct is just a side-effect of unions and structs being handled the same way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The Standard is IMHO pretty horrible there, especially given "modern" aliasing rules which assume that an untagged structure that appears within a union won't alias a tagged structure with the same members.