# array take size of struct in union

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a union in a project i'm working on that represents a USB joystick report:

```
union {
    struct{
        uint8_t xaxis;
        uint8_t yaxis;
        uint8_t xraxis;
        uint8_t yraxis;
        uint8_t zraxis;
        uint8_t slider;

        uint8_t buttons8;
        uint8_t buttons16;
    };
    uchar buffer[8];
} report;
```

this way i can easily put the values into the struct members and use the buffer member to send that data over USB, however I end up modifying this union for different projects (different resolutions on the axis, more/less buttons etc) so then i have to work out what the new size of the struct is to declare the array with the same size.

is there a way to automatically make the array the same size? i thought of using `sizeof` which requires me to change the struct like this:

```
union {
    struct _data{ // either this
        uint8_t xaxis;
        uint8_t yaxis;
        uint8_t xraxis;
        uint8_t yraxis;
        uint8_t zraxis;
        uint8_t slider;

        uint8_t buttons8;
        uint8_t buttons16;
    } data; // or this
    uchar buffer[8];
} report;
```

but then i can no longer put data into the struct like this:

```
report.xaxis = value;
```

but instead:

```
report.data.xaxis = value;
```

which i don't want.

is there a way to do this cleanly?

Comment: Don’t use an untagged structure. Then use `sizeof(structure tag)` for the dimension.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you elaborate? i can't see how that lets me avoid having to do something like `report.data.xaxis = value`

Comment: Like Lundin shows in his answer.  Distinguish between a structure tag which allows you to refer to the structure type and a member name. You should be able to use an anonymous structure, but you need the tag so you can refer to the type and get its size.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - If it's tagged, it's not an anonymous structure. At least not according to [n1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p13).

Comment: @StoryTeller: a tagged structure can be an anonymous member of the union, just as an untagged structure can be too. I am out of here for a few hours — I need to sleep sometime. But while untagged structures are one sort of anonymous, you can have anonymous elements of a structure or union, and those anonymous elements can be tagged or untagged structures (or various other types).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I can't find any mention of anonymous members other than structures or unions. And the grammar production seems to indicate the declarator of a member is only optional for bit-field. I do not wish to deprive you of sleep, but when you are back, I'll appreciate if you can point me in the right direction with regard to this being standard or not.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The standard uses the terms 'unnamed member' and 'anonymous struct' or 'anonymous union'.  I was misremembering and don't have a copy of the standard on my iPhone (nor do I have eidetic memory), so I got the terminology wrong.  (The 'or various other types' is comment is wrong; I put the mistakes down to sleep deprivation at the time.)

Comment: I think your requirements are conflicting — one of them is going to have to give.  Either you treasure the abbreviated access notation `report.rzaxis` (what happened to the `zaxis` member?), or you value the ability to size the array automatically — AFAICS, you can't have both at the same time (without resorting to abominable macro trickery — so abominable I'm not even going to discuss it, though I work with systems where it is widely (ab)used).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd rather avoid ugly macro hackery, I'll probably lose the abbreviation, as for the `zaxis` i was restructuring some example code that came with the digispark arduino framework I'm working with, youd have to ask the origional author, however they had written it so the calling code had to do all the byte alignment into the buffer the hard way, meaning many parts of the code needed rework if the structure changed

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 is to get a standard C compiler. Then you can use an anonymous struct. To get the appropriate size for the array, use a struct tag, which is only needed internally by the union.

```
typedef union {
    struct data {
        uint8_t xaxis;
        uint8_t yaxis;
        uint8_t xraxis;
        uint8_t yraxis;
        uint8_t zraxis;
        uint8_t slider;
        uint8_t buttons8;
        uint8_t buttons16;
    }; 
    uint8_t buffer[sizeof(struct data)];
} report_t;

...

  report_t r; 
  r.xaxis = 123;
```

Comment: I do get the warning "does not declare anything" with pedantic

Comment: @JamesKent Which compiler are you using and how is it configured? This compiles cleanly on an older version of gcc but with C11 support.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala gcc 4.9.1 `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` compiles cleanly.

Comment: This really being an anonymous [structure, standard-wise, is kinda debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524573/817643).

Comment: @JamesKent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11 they need C11 support.

Comment: @StoryTeller gcc seems to believe it is, I can't compile it with -std=c99. Anyway it doesn't matter what it is called, as long as it compiles and can be used as intended.

Comment: i'm this is on arduino 1.6.9 which according to versions file is using 4.8.1-arduino5

Comment: @JamesKent Then it should have C11 support. But older versions than gcc 5.x has to be told explicitly not to be trash, with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. If you don't include that, you aren't using a standard compiler, but a "gnu90" compiler. Isn't Arduino actually using some sort of simplified C++ btw?

Comment: *"Step 1 is to get a standard C compiler"* - If there's a contention point in the standard about this, I don't see why we need to bash the OP's compiler for it, that's my point. Of course it won't work at all in C99 mode, since there isn't *any* notion of an anonymous struct in C99.

Comment: @StoryTeller C11 has been out for 7 years now. There is no excuse not to use a standard ISO C compiler, particularly not if you are using gcc. The OP's compiler _is_ modern enough, it is just incorrectly configured.

Comment: According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status), C11 anonymous struct was included in gcc 4.6.

Comment: *"There is no excuse not to use a standard ISO C compiler, particularly not if you are using gcc"* - What does that have to do with anything? I never argued against it. But if the standard itself isn't clear on the validity of this (as I mentioned before, it's debatable), then that's unlikely to be of help.

Comment: @StoryTeller Isn't `typedef struct { foo; } bar;` another issue, though? I actually don't believe the struct in my code counts as an anonymous struct, because it does have a tag. But gcc seems to think it is anonymous still.

Comment: @Lundin - In retrospect, it is. Truth be told, I'm kinda baffled by this. I've seen and used code like you presented. But then I hit a brick wall when trying to prove it is pure standard C.

Comment: @StoryTeller Proving that it is standard C is the easy part, simply read chapter 6.7.2.1.

Comment: @Lundin - I did, hence my complaints. p13 says *"An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier with **no tag** is called an anonymous structure"*. So it's not an anonymous structure. And it doesn't *have* to be, like you said. But the problem is that I don't see anything that would suggest it's okay to omit the declarator otherwise.

Comment: Using GCC 7.2.0 and `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c union71.c`, I get the "does not declare anything" (error because of `-Werror`, but a warning otherwise).  Written with the tag, this defines a structure type (that can be referred to as `struct data`), but it doesn't define a structure member.  I got confused; it's also subtle as a snake.  It's basically saying "you could move the `struct data { … };` before the `union` and it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you get the same if you include `-pedantic-errors`?

Comment: @Lundin: Succinctly, yes — no change with `-pedantic-errors` added.  I'm compiling on a Mac with a home-built (but not specially modified) GCC 7.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `offsetof()` for this with the last element in the struct

```
union
{
    struct data
    {
        uint8_t xaxis;
        uint8_t yaxis;
        uint8_t xraxis;
        uint8_t yraxis;
        uint8_t zraxis;
        uint8_t slider;

        uint8_t buttons8;
        uint8_t buttons16;
    };
    uint8_t buffer[offsetof(struct data, buttons16)+1];
} report;
```

Comment: i see where you're going with this, but it still requires some fiddling if the last member changes or changes type (could be a uint16_t)

Comment: Please note that there may be padding at the end of the struct. Not taking this in account might cause problems if you declare an array of unions. For example code such as: `report arr[n]; memcpy(x, arr, 5*sizeof(arr[0].buffer)); // copy 5 items` might fail horribly.

Comment: This code runs into the same problem that the code in (the current edition of) [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48317949/15168) runs into.  See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317843/array-take-size-of-struct-in-union/48318186?noredirect=1#comment83639148_48317949) for some information.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions other people have proposed here will work. However, they are all hacks, due to your use of a union for ease of conversion to bytes. There is a cleaner solution, which is to do away with the union. Simply make your `struct` the top-level type, and have your function that sends data over USB take parameters of `(void * data, size_t length)` . Then, you can easily send any data type over USB.